# submitted form is not completely saved in the database

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate, spring-mvc, submit

In my current spring project, one of the renderized forms is the follow:

```
        <form id="Usuario" class="form" role="form" method="post" action="/caixa/Usuario/insert">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <field-box>
                  <label>login</label>
                  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="form-control" />
                </field-box>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <field-box>
                  <label>senha</label>
                  <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="form-control" />
                </field-box>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <field-box>
                  <label>nome</label>
                  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control" />
                </field-box>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <field-box>
                  <label>sobrenome</label>
                  <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" class="form-control" />
                </field-box>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <field-box>
                  <label>email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" />
                </field-box>
             </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <field-box>
                  <label>role</label>
                  <select multiple="multiple" name="role.id" id="role" class="form-control option" data-classe="Role">
                  </select>
                </field-box>
            </li>

            <button type="submit" id="cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>

            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="yes" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                Cadastro efetuado com sucesso
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id="not" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <span class="text"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
```

the data submitted through this form is related to this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    @Input
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "senha")
    @Input(type = "password")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    @Input
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "sobrenome")
    @Input
    private String sobrenome;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Input(type = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="role_members", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_user")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_role")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Select(classe = Role.class)
    private List<Role> role;
}
```

the submission process is handled by this jquery code:

```
    $(document).on("submit", "form.form", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $( this ), url = $form.attr( "action" );
        var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );
        posting.done(function( data ) {
            if(data == "") {
                $("#yes").show();
            } else {
                var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
                $("#not").find(".text").html( $temp.remove('head').html() );
                $("#not").show();
            }
            $("form.form").each(function(){
                this.reset();
            });
        });
    });
```

and by this methods in my controller, service and dao classes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "insert")
@ResponseBody
public void insert(@ModelAttribute("object") E object) throws Exception {
    try {
        serv.insert(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public void insert(E object) {
    dao.persist(object);
}

@Transactional
public void persist(E object) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(object);
}
```

but when I run the application and open this view in my browser, and submit this form, the data is saved in the database without the data from the `<select>` field. I check the browser console (in the firefox), and verify all the fields are being submitted to server, but the field `role` is the only one which it's not stored.

Anyone can see what's the pronlem here?

Comment: You must make sure you're passing in an array as it seems to be a multi choice select group for you. Shouldn't the name of the role select field simply be `role` instead of `role.id`?

Comment: @Vaelyr no, I try use `role` instead of `role.id`, but in this way no data is saved in the database, and I get an error.

Comment: Can you check what kind of data are you passing in through your post request from your browser. Is the role actually sent or not?

Comment: @Vaelyr yes, as I said in the question, when I check the browser console, all the fields are being send to server.

Comment: can you post code for Role also. specially relationship between Usuario and Role

Comment: @Sujata the class Role have only three fields: Id, Name and a List of Permissions. The relationship between Role and Permission have the same rules as viewed above for field role from Usuario.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in column names you have given in  @JoinTable(name="role_members", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="**fk_user**")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="**fk_role**")})

column name fk_user is not present in your entity class. If you want to use different name then use referencedColumnName attribute and give actual field name.
eg. We are using id from both entities then after change it will be like

```
@JoinTable(name="role_members", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_user", referencedColumnName="id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_role",referencedColumnName="id")})
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: I add this to my code, but the issue still happening: the insert is processed with no errors, but the values for the role field are not stored.